# Magento 2 - How to call a custom phtml file in another phtml file, xml layout, static block and cms page

Tags: magento, magento2

My file is in app/design/frontent/vendor_name/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/test.phtml

How to call this files in another phtml file, xml layout, static block and cms page

Please Help

Answer (score 14):

**In `xml layout` file**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"/>
```

**In `cms blocks and cms pages`**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}
```

**In a `phtml` file**

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml')) ?>
```